# como definir variables progresivamente

Tags: c++, string

Estoy programando en C++, quiero crear varios objetos a partir de una lista  Vector, algo asi como:

```
Grafica grafic1 = Grafica(subdirectorio, "CHDRAUIB"); // ROJO
grafic1.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
grafic1.Carga();

Grafica grafic2 = Grafica(subdirectorio, "FIBRAPL14");  // AMARILLO
grafic2.Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0F);
grafic2.Carga();

Grafica grafic3 = Grafica(subdirectorio, "CYDSASAA");   // CIAN
grafic3.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
grafic3.Carga();

Grafica grafic5 = Grafica(subdirectorio, "GFNORTEO");   // VIOLETA
grafic5.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0F);
grafic5.Carga();
```

Creo que lo mejor seria que a al objeto de la clase grafica se le añadiera un número consecutivo `grafic + num`
Me imagine que si puedo hacer `strings` e irlos concatenándolos podría ir añadiendo los números y después hacer que la cadena la lea como si fuera código ejecutable, pero no encuentro la librería y su función.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Si `Grafica` es un vector podrías crear una sola variable, por ejemplo `graficas` y utilizar el método `push_back()` para agregar elementos

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, Grafica es una clase, la idea es hacer muchos objetos Grafica cono nombres que contengan un numero ascendente.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar arreglos o vectores para hacerlo

### Vectores

Si no sabes cuántas variables vas a "crear" y quieres agregar elementos de forma dinámica, podrías utilizar un vector. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo creando un vector de tipo `int` (Puedes sustituirlo por tu clase `Grafica` así `vector<Grafica>`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> miVector;
    
    miVector.push_back(15);
    miVector.push_back(10);
    
    cout<<miVector[0];
    cout<<miVector[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Para agregar elementos de forma dinámica utilizas `push_back()` en tu caso tendrías que pasar los parámetros de tu clase, en el ejemplo se muestran solo enteros.

Para acceder a cada uno de los elementos del vector utilizamos el índice del elemento (Empezando por cero) a través de los corchetes `[]`

### Arreglos

Otra opción es crear un arreglo, la diferencia es que al declararlo necesitas el tamaño del arreglo por lo que no es dinámico. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo creando un arreglo de tipo `int` (Puedes sustituirlo por tu clase `Grafica` así `Grafica nombreVariable[tamaño]`). En el ejemplo siguiente estoy creando un arreglo de 10 elementos del tipo `int`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int miArreglo[10];
    
    miArreglo[0] = 15;
    miArreglo[1] = 10;
    
    cout<<miArreglo[0];
    cout<<miArreglo[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Para acceder a cada uno de los elementos del arreglo utilizamos el índice del elemento (Empezando por cero) a través de los corchetes `[]` (Igual que el vector). Pero al declararlo ya indicamos cuántos elementos existen, por lo tanto para asignar información a cada elemento tenemos que utilizar su índice, de esta forma `miArreglo[0] = 15;` es decir, asignamos el valor `15` al índice `0`

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, lo que quiero es generar las definiciones de los objetos en forma dinámica, pero estoy entendiendo que eso no es posible porque C++ es compilado.

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo dinámico es utilizando vectores, pero si lo que tu quieres es generar tal cual el nombre de las variables entonces no se puede. Con los vectores generarías los objetos tipo `Grafica` en un vector y podrías ir agregando elementos con `push_back()`, yo creo que sería una de las formas más cercanas a hacer algo parecido a lo que quieres

Answer (score 0):

> al objeto de la clase grafica se le añadiera un número consecutivo `grafic + num` Me imagine que si puedo hacer strings e irlos concatenándolos podría ir añadiendo los números y después hacer que la cadena la lea como si fuera código ejecutable

Lo que estás pidiendo es un imposible. No se pueden nombrar variables dinámicamente, y los *strings* no son variables de tipo `Grafica`. Lo más parecido a lo que te ronda la cabeza sería usar macros:

```
#define GRAFIC(N, SD, C, R, G, B) Grafica grafic##N{SD, C}; grafic##N.Color(R, G, B); grafic##N.Carga();

int main()
{
    std::string subdirectorio{};

    GRAFIC(1, subdirectorio, "CHDRAUIB",  1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    GRAFIC(2, subdirectorio, "FIBRAPL14", 1.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    GRAFIC(3, subdirectorio, "CYDSASAA",  0.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    GRAFIC(5, subdirectorio, "GFNORTEO",  1.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    std::cout << &grafic1 << ' '
        << &grafic2 << ' '
        << &grafic3 << ' '
        << &grafic5 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBda8IwFIavm19xsKAVMrE6b1SEWmcnjDrqdjHYTZZ@EKiJpOluSn971y@nxd40hyfnyXtO6eXyRGPCo6LQGadx6gewZiJRMiDnDbqxkjAebRAqi5QqcCQJGSUoQ1pbGlTwREGi/OWy6YYhhh44hixH2q9gPtgiFtIIY0EUhvvjvofIiBg1yFcI6X4QMh6A41n7g224GE47DDYGD4ODYTu@jgZRfeq6m9Ud@epGJk3wVencNHFlEuMKzoRxY1xteb9Ckv74TAZUCclEVk2lteOYuHuJYWC/7jzr87AdYABzEmKYtp8y46rNHrX9YetZ72/mc@nVmvmozXvSvnYn62RZVdr0XzM72uJRc/bu0ft4OXaHbLR2dypSBes1DJt/ZVb1CEZI025w1gfnfXBRw28@qt6XgUolh@kK5UXxBw)</kbd>. Pero no te aconsejo esa idea, creo que en realidad buscas usar un `std::map<std::string, Grafica>`:

```
std::string subdirectorio{};
std::map<std::string, Grafica> graficas;

graficas.emplace("grafic1", Grafica{subdirectorio, "CHDRAUIB"});
graficas.emplace("grafic2", Grafica{subdirectorio, "FIBRAPL14"});
graficas.emplace("grafic3", Grafica{subdirectorio, "CYDSASAA"});
graficas.emplace("grafic5", Grafica{subdirectorio, "GFNORTEO"});

graficas.at("grafic1").Color(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
graficas.at("grafic2").Color(1.f, 1.f, 0.f);
graficas.at("grafic3").Color(0.f, 1.f, 1.f);
graficas.at("grafic5").Color(1.f, 0.f, 1.f);

for (auto &[k, v] : graficas)
    v.Carga();
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJdb4IwFIav6a84YYmBiER03qgzQZ3OZJmLbhfLsouufKQZtKQUbwh/XYaiiIly0568PH3OCS2Jog4JMPPz/IEyEiSOC2PKYylcHE7QJSsSyvx6EuJoglCRJ0TCUmCPEoxSpJxKjXAWS4ilMxyWh6FlwI1QhzRDyo5TB2Y84ELzAo6lAfWtzmDhY@0YZCOEKJMQYso0/dC7Lo6TX4cKl0guKE8LtvxajD2uYcZ59An4ZREXVuVcm24YBZi4mlomllodSK8aGKDOXuYb@3M1VTN9dN/QazAsVtON/f5qPTYr@k1DfM239ta2mw2DBsNy8bbefDyvj4aaAsvLT9DN8qos0zOge1quGl7o3jVtNdP9iu5WtHWXHtyYpKSR4nEBGk4kh9b3nwG7HxhWV6wjRdmZp6d0gIUrE8GgO0JZnu@JF2A/zjvFO3ki7XYP/wM)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias, ya entendí que lo que quiero hacer no es posible en C++, y que la solución es con  std::map. mil gracias